# Wordpress Plugin add_rewrite_rule() not working

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Here's my code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_rules' );
function add_author_rules() { 
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "/page1\/(\w*)\/part01/g",
        "page1",
        "top");
}
```

The actual URL is *www.domain.com/page1/anyhere/part01*.

*part1* is just a custom word I wanted to add in the URL (it can be any word), but the URL above is still 404 error.

What is wrong with the above code?

Thanks in advance. Have a good day.

Comment: Just replace `/page1\/(\w*)\/part01/g` with `/page1\/(\w*)\/part01/` I guess (though I'd replace `*` with `+`). If `part1` can be anything but `/`, just use `[^\/]*` instead: `/page1\/(\w+)\/[^\/]+/`. Also, I'd use single quotes around this pattern.

Comment: Also, by the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule): *IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.*

Comment: This is now my code but it still returns 404:
`add_action( 'init', 'add_author_rules' );`
`function add_author_rules() { `
`add_rewrite_rule(`
`'/page1\/(\w*)\/part01/',`
`'page1',`
`'top'`
`);`
`}`

Comment: I also did what @FelipeElia says.

Comment: The regex code should be simply `'page1/([\w]*)/part01/?'` without scaping the `/` or putting any modifier. The second parameter should point to index.php with query vars appended to it, like `'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]'`. Where will you use the matched content by `\w`?